# Runnable run() method called twice sometimes?

Tags: android

I am a new Android developer. I am using the Handler class to schedule some operations. So I am creating runnable objects that calls some of my instance methods.

But I have a problem. Sometimes my run() method in Runnable object is called twice.

What could be the problem??

and there is the code

```
//deneme is a Handler.
deneme.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                    randomOyna();
                    //the instance method that I call.
            }
        }, 1000);
```

Comment: We're gonna need some code for context. Just the relevant snippets would do.

Comment: then you are really calling the `run()` method twice. log the stack trace to see the call flow

Comment: but how. I am only calling the above code! No more.

Answer (score 0):

Can't see a mistake just by looking the hint you gave us... But you might try plain old java to run threads instead of handler... Good luck...

[Look here for more details](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/timed-ui-updates.html)

Answer (score 0):

If don't schedule your `Handler` to run on another `Thread` than the UI-thread, there might be a hidden delay in the execution because your `Runnable` will also run on the UI-thread and thus will only be allowed to run when there is "time" for it. With this hidden delay, it might seem like it is run twice but in reality it's just and over-delayed running before a regular delayed `Runnable`.

Comment: I have put a textview to the screen and incremented it when run is entered. And I saw that it incerements 2. So I think it is actually called twice.